# How to add Items to a ComboBox from a different Form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, combobox

I have tried this many times, many different ways. And I can't get the `ComboBox` populated.

```
public partial class Login : Form
    {
    public void populateTenants(dynamic tenants)
        {
            Form1 main = new Form1();
            foreach (dynamic tenant in tenants.tenants)
            {
                string tenantName=tenant.name;
                main.addTenant(tenantName);
            }
        }
    }
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void addTenant(string item)
        {
            cbTenants.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

I can do this and it works great:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cbTenants.Items.Add("Test");
        }
    }
```

And I can do this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public void addTenant(string item)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item);
        }
    }
```

And I get a ton of MessageBoxes.

Comment: The first code snippet should work. The question is though, where is the `main.Show` call?

Answer (score 0):

You can make first Form's combobox 'Modifires' Private to Public and can get items other forms a simple foreach loop;

You can get items:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
foreach (string item in frm.comboBox1.Items)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Like this ...

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't add object to the combobox.
I can get items to add If I add a button on the same form and click it...
But coming from another form... It doesn't work at all.
Any other suggestions?